# Como abrir a Calculadora usando intent?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar uma aplicação Nativa na minha aplicação.
Gostaria de colocar um menu de calculadora, quando o usuário clicasse, abrisse a calculadora do android.

Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda não consegui. Vou abrir outro tópico para explicar melhor. Posso ? Pois queria colocar partes do meu código aqui para entenderem melhor. E pela resposta aqui tem limite de caracteres.

Comment: O foco desta pergunta é como abrir a calculadora, se nenhuma das resposta o atende deve comentar em cada uma delas o porquê. Só deve criar outra pergunta se o foco for outro. Em todo o caso pode sempre [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/131269/edit) a pergunta e acrescentar mais informações.

Answer (score 1):

Deve utilizar um [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) juntamente com o método startActivity();

Pelo que se pode ler na documentação, para lançar a calculadora o *Intent* deve indicar a categoria [CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.makeMainSelectorActivity (Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
            Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
startActivity(intent);
```

Testei o código mas **não funciona**.

Encontrei este [aqui](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/06/08/android-open-the-calculator-from-android/) que testei e **funciona**(pelo menos no emulador).

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.calculator2",
                                      "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Viva,
 o seguinte código garante que a tua app abre a calculadora em qualquer dispositivo.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
    map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
    items.add(map);
 }
}
```

//Podes agora abrir a calculadora executando:

```
if(items.size()>=1){
String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (i != null)
  startActivity(i);
} 
else{
      // Application not found
}
```

Esta info foi encontrada aqui -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662506/how-to-call-android-calculator-on-my-app-for-all-phones

Dá uma olhada à documentação Android no link abaixo, para saberes como abrir outras apps nativas.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html